# Sed - How can I insert a string after a certain line AND a certain character?

Tags: sed

I need to insert some lines of code into a file. The problem is, I want to insert it after some function calling AND after the semicolon behind it, too.

I'd like to achieve this just with `sed`, but I don't know why.

---

#### Example:

Source code snippet:

```
10 printf("asdf");
11
12 myFunc()
13
14 ;
```

Here I want to insert the snippet behind the `myFunc()` call, but I can't insert it directly to the line 13, but to the line 15.

#### Desired code after insertion:

```
10 printf("asdf");
11
12 myFunc()
13
14 ;
15 SNIPPET
```

My best attempt is this:

```
sed -e '13 i\SNIPPET'
```

Which obviously doesn't "wait" for the semicolon.

So, is there any way I could combine those conditions, so I'd insert my code snippet after the first semicolon after the line number ***?

Comment: Please add sample output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `sed` is good for manipulating text **lines**, if you want to do something else it's probably a good idea to use `awk`, it's a bit more feature-rich.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
sed '
  /myFunc()/!b
  :1 
  s/;/; SNIPPET/;t
  n;b1'
```

Or for line 13:

```
sed '
  13!b
  :1 
  s/;/; SNIPPET/;t
  n;b1'
```

Comment: The second one looks exactly like what I need - could you please add a little description? I'd like to understand what is it doing exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `sed` - I don't think it's a good tool for this purpose, due to it's inherent line-oriented nature.

I would instead suggest:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    #print current line (because we insert _after) 
    print;
    #extract the number. If you need to work on _actual_ line number, you need $.
    my ($num) = m/^(\d+)/;
    if ( $num > 13 and m/;/ ) {
        #print snippet, bail out
        print ++$num, " SNIPPET\n";    
        last;
    }
}
#print rest of file
print <>;
```

Note - this extracts the numbering from the content, based on your example. I couldn't quite tell if you wanted actual line numbers - although `sed -e '13 ..'` implies that you do.

In which case:

```
if ( $. > 13 and m/;/ ) {
    print "SNIPPET\n"; 
    last;
}
```